# how do I fix sql error in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I fix this error? I searched for several forums, but I could not solve it! SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user' @ 'localhost' (using SQL: select * from table where column = number)

Comment: If Laravel is using MySQL, then those startup errors are not related to your issue (although you should fix them at some point). The actually error is "access denied", which usually means you're using the wrong username/password combination.

Comment: makes sense, my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database consists of tables. You will populate the tables of the database using

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

However, you need to create a database first, and use the database name for DB_DATABASE. Creating the database is independent of Laravel. See https://medium.com/@connorleech/build-an-online-forum-with-laravel-initial-setup-and-seeding-part-1-a53138d1fffc for some information on creating a database.

Make sure your .env file has the correct database parameters. e.g.:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=name_of_database
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Also of note, php artisan config:cache to make sure laravel uses the new configuration.

Comment: @ManuelAlejandroCaetano Wouldn't php artisan config:clear make more sense to make sure the configuration cache isn't causing an issue?

Comment: I usually use cache out of habit, but yes, for that purpose it makes more sense to use config:clear.

Comment: yes, but my I do not know the name of my DB_DATABASE because I would like to popular it with php artisan migrate --seed. Understand me ?

Comment: @IvoBrunoSilva I updated the answer with information on database vs. table

Comment: Thanks, I used this php artisan migrate --seed command, however I got an error named Class RolesTableSeeder
https://imgur.com/TWtA6HX

Comment: Follow the guide here for database seeding: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding. Also, if I answered your original question, please mark it answered.